# Shared android project Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have an Android Project, and I would like to create a similar application. But the only difference between both apps is only on the `Application Name`, The `style`, `Colors` and `drawables`. Thus, the Java code is the same, but the resources are partially different.

My target is to have something like this:

1 - Shared Project with the complete logic.

2 - The first extension of the Shared project: Overwrite the `style.xml`, `color.xml`, `drawable/*`and `string.xml`.

3 - The Second extension of the Shared project: Overwrite the `style.xml`, `color.xml`, `drawable/*` and `string.xml`

Comment: Android Gradle plugin allows you to use flavours, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Egor - You're actually answering the question. Write your comment as answer!

Comment: @Egor: By using Android Gradle plugin, I may change the structure of my project and so on. I have started yesterday to convert my Main project (shared) to a Library without the Gradle plugin and after some changes, in the new project, which use the shared project it was possible to run my application. My next step is to try to overwrite the `string.xml`-values as well as `color.xml`-values. I would post a complete solution in the common days, if I solve the problem inside eclipse without the Gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by doing following:

Problem: Project A (Initial Project), Project B (Fork Project)

Solution: 
1 - Create the project A, then configures it as Library. This project must implement the Android-Application class ( Application A)

2 - create the project B and make its depends to The project B.

3 - In the new project B, create a new class Application B, which is a extention of the Application A (`Application B extends Aplication A`).

4 - The manifest of the project B, can be 1-1 copied from the Project B, but the application-class must be different: It must correspond to the location of the class `Application B`.

5 - regarding the ressource (string.xml, style.xml, colors and drawable). It's not important to copy them inside the new project. you can create a corresponding file, if you want to overwrite a old value, then set it in the new ressource file:

For example: Project A: 
string.xml has the value: `name="app_name" - application A`
 For the project B, it's just important to create in the string.xml a value with the same name to overwrite the old value: `name="app_name" - application B`. This can also be applied for the color and others ressource.

6 - If you want to change a image, you just need to use a different image, but with the name of the to overwritten image and put it at the same place of the Project B (for example drawable).

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. All you to do is the following,

```
File->Import->Android->Existing Android Code Into workspace
```

Then select the project you want to import and give it a new name.

Comment: thank you for your help, but your are completely wrong. I'm no trying to import a existing project into eclipse. Please read my statement again.